# will php/apache garbage collection delete session files?

Tags: session, garbage-collection

I set the session file in php.ini to expire in one month (in fact they are saved in browsers for 30 days) but after hours when I reopen one page the session cookie is still there (in the browser) but the data in the session is gone. Is PHP deleting the session files? How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK nevermind answer is [session.gc_maxlifetime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime)